# Multi-participant registration

Tags: civievent

I'm setting up reg for an event, and standard reg is fine ($/individual) however we'd like to add some options to this, for example family registration at a slightly different price.

The issue I'm having, and haven't gotten my head around figuring out, is how to set up registration and price sets to handle this. Individual should be $10 each, family should be $15 (and charge only once instead of per registrant).

Latest version of Civicrm and on WordPress here.

Comment: Still looking for some help with this.